# How to find value by key in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm not sure if this can be done in Redis, but is there a way to look up the key by value in redis?

Suppose that I have a redis DB where the key is the symptom_id and the value is the symptom_name.

For exammple:

```
{
    "symptom_id:1": "headache",
    "symptom_id:2": "stomach pain",
    "symptom_id:3": "cough"
}
```

Let's say I want to find the symptom ID of "cough". Is it possible to do so? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: There's no built-in way. You need to build a [secondary index](https://redis.io/topics/indexes), i.e. an index from value to key.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for clearing that up @for_stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it regularly, use secondary index, as @for_stack suggested. This is a fast and proper way.

If you need an ad-hoc solution, you can iterate keys by pattern with `SCAN symptom_id:* ...` (see [scan](https://redis.io/commands/scan)), and look at their values.